# Cloud 9 IDE How do I fix my cursor?

Tags: cursor, cloud9-ide

Every time I type the cursor inserts my code and it gets very annoying.  How do I change it where the cursors doesn't insert.  Using Chrome windows 8 pc.  Thanks in advance

Comment: Try pressing the "Insert" button on your keyboard..?

Answer (score 0):

It's happening because your current application is running. Stop your App by pressing Ctrl+C and then starts typing it will work fine.